# Function returns None no matter what

Tags: python, return

I have this function which is supposed to give the value of a linked list node by its index.
I can print the value the line before but when I return the value it somehow turns into None.

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, next_node=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next_node


def create_list(linkedlist, i, j=1):
    if i == 0:
        return
    l = ListNode(j)
    linkedlist.next = l
    create_list(linkedlist.next, i-1, j+1)


def index(head, idx=0):
    if idx == 0:
        return head.val
    print(idx)
    index(head.next, idx-1)


link = ListNode()
create_list(link, 5)
print(index(link, 4))
```

Output:

```
4
3
2
1
None
```

I even returned an integer in the function but that turned into None as well.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Where is the second return statement?

Comment: I don't understand.What I was trying to say was that instead of "return head.val" I just put "return 0" and it returned None.Thanks for responding.

Comment: See answer ... help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return the recursive call as well:

```
def index(head, idx=0):
    if idx == 0:
        return head.val
    print(idx)
    return index(head.next, idx - 1)
```

You're missing the return on the last line.

For the other function

```
def create_list(linkedlist,i,j=1):
    if i == 0:
        return linkedlist   # missing object to return in terminal case
    l = ListNode(j)
    linkedlist.next = l
    return create_list(linkedlist.next,i-1,j+1)  # missing return on recursive call
```

Comment: Oh I didn't know that.Thanks for the help.

Comment: Well in the "create_list" function since it just references them I didn't notice the problem and that kinda confused me. Thanks.